# Long form of injecting a service in a class constructor

Tags: angular, service, constructor

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {
}
```

what is the long form of injecting a service in a class constructor?
I want to rework the above into somethign like:

```
private myService;
constructor() {
    this.myService = new MyService();
}
```

but now it screams that MyService expects two parameters (in the long form)

Why does the short form work without explicitly giving the params?

Comment: Upvote the answer if this helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ways its the same, just that you are delegating the assignment part to the system and you are consuming it whatever you need.

Assume if your service has dependencies then you would need,

```
const dep1 = new Dep1();
const subDep = new SubDep();
const dep2 = new Dep2(subDep);
this.myService = new MyService(dep1, dep2)
```

always better to go with the first approach, because system does the things automatically